Route Outgoing Traffic over Wireless Network, Route Incoming Traffic over Wired Network
I have two network interfaces (eno1, and wls4) on the same physical computer, running Ubuntu 22.04. eno1 has a public static IP, at xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, and wls4 will use DHCP. Both network interfaces provide an Internet connection, albeit via two different networks.
The computer serves websites (to the wider Internet) at the public static IP (at xxx.xxx.xxx.xx), but cannot/should not make outgoing connections to the Internet via this network (on eno1).
The Internet connection on wls4 is meant to allow the computer to connect to the Internet (for updates, accessing APIs etc.), but not to accept any incoming traffic.
How do I route ONLY outgoing traffic over wls4, but keep incoming traffic (including SSH) untouched over eno1? The computer hosts websites and services, so connections over eno1 cannot be affected.
From my own reading and research, I get the impression that I do not necessarily need to route incoming connections on eno1 (and I only need to route outgoing traffic on wls4?)? Once a connection is initiated at my public static ip, the connection should persist? But i have no idea how to direct traffic out over wls4, without breaking my current connection on eno1. When I activate wls4 and eno1 at the same time, I'm unable to SSH in at the public static IP, or access websites hosted at the public static IP
this is the output i get from route -n when I have both interfaces connected
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.249.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wls4
xxx.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.19.50.39    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wls4
172.19.215.140  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wls4
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge


EDIT
I've moved my wls4 routes to a separate routing table, and added the policy-routing rule that selects this table for any packets sent from my wls4 IP address. But for some reason I still can't get Linux to use wls4 for outgoing connections. (if I do curl ifconfig.me --interface <wls4_ip_address>, I manage to connect, so the wls4 internet connection is working).
My current route -V output
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
xxx.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4ee50e2ba8a2
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge

my output from ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local
400:    from 10.249.21.247/16 lookup wls4
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

and my output from ip route list table wls4
default via 10.249.0.1 dev wls4
10.249.0.1 dev wls4 scope link
172.19.50.39 via 10.249.0.1 dev wls4
172.19.215.140 via 10.249.0.1 dev wls4

I'm not too sure what I'm missing, and would appreciate any help!

(Step 0: Get a second Ethernet card instead of running a server on Wi-Fi?)
Copy (or move) your wls4 routes to an alternative routing table. Not sure if netplan has such an option (it ought to, because its systemd-networkd backend definitely does), but if you were to do it manually:
ip -4 route add default via <gw> dev wls4 table 444

(If it turns out to be not feasible, you can do it the other way around and move the eno1 route instead – it doesn't matter which.)
Add a policy-routing rule that selects this table for any packets sent from your wls4 IP address (as above, not sure about netplan, but systemd-networkd can create policy rules):
ip -4 rule add pref 400 from <ip>/32 lookup 444

This happens to break local subnet access as table 444 no longer has your "local /24 subnet" route. To compensate for this, you can either a) add a special 'throw' rule that falls through to the main table:
ip -4 route add throw 192.168.1.0/24 table 444

or b) add another policy-routing rule that checks the main table for local subnet access (i.e. everything except default route):
ip -4 rule add pref 100 from any lookup main suppress_prefixlen 0


Sorry, but I'm not quite sure I understand. I don't currently have any routes for wls4, nor any routes for eno1. I've edited my question for a bit more clarity.

I'm pretty sure you do – if you have Internet access, then you will have a default route at the very minimum (along with a "local subnet" route).

Ah - I meant I don’t have any static routes for either interface. Sorry! Have posted the output of route -n, if that helps!

The default route aka 0.0.0.0/0 still counts as a route for all intents and purposes. If you have two Internet connections (ethernet and wireless), then you would accordingly have two such routes – one over ethernet (for reply packets), another over wifi (for new connections) – and you'd need to configure Linux to choose the correct one, which is what the post is about.

Keep in mind that IP routing is almost entirely packet-based: each packet, not each connection, has its route chosen individually. So even for incoming connections, your server still needs to send out reply packets, and those replies are also outgoing traffic (even if they "belong to" inbound connections), which is one of the most important points to remember when dealing with any IP routing.

How can I add a policy routing rule to select table 444 (in the example above) for packets coming from wls4, if it requires my IP, but wls4 uses DHCP (and so the IP address changes?)

DHCP shouldn't necessarily imply the address changing – as long as the server is online (or not offline for longer than its lease time) it should be renewing the same address lease forever. But if it changes within the same subnet (like the same /24) you can specify that whole subnet as the 'from', I think that shouldn't cause problems. A more reliable method though is to use iptables rules to apply a mark to the incoming packet, save it as a connmark, then use another rule for outgoing packets to restore the connmark onto the packet mark - and have the policy rule match on fwmark instead.
